# Can't open a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I cannot use the json file, what is the problem and what should i do?
I have this code:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import nltk
import json
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer

intents = json.loads(open("asdf12.json").read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['?','!','.',',']

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.append(word_list)
        documents.append((word_list, intent['tag']))
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])   

print(documents)
```

and this json file named asdf12.json in the same folder:

```
{"intents":[
    {"tag": "greetings",
    "patterns":["hello","hey","hi","good day","greetings","what's up?","how is it going?"],
    "responses": ["Hello!","Hey!","What can i do for you?"]
    },
    {"tag":"goodbye",
    "patterns":["cya","bye","goodbye","see ya","see you later","I am leaving"],
    "responses":["Sad to see you go :(","Bye!","Goodbye!","See you later!"]
    }
]}
```

when i try to run the commands i get these errors:

```
tfai12/tfaich1.py", line 14, in <module>
    intents = json.loads(open("asdf12.json").read())
Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. You must be reading a different file. What happens if you execute: `print(open("asdf12.json").read()[:15])`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried your code and it didn't print anything.

Comment: Ok, well, you have the wrong file. Keep moving files around until you get: `{"intents":[`

Comment: Does the JSON file have a Unicode BOM? Can you reveal the first few bytes with `od -cH` or `xxd`?

Comment: I don't know how to reveal bytes, can you please help me with it? i use windows. @tripleee

Comment: I already suggested two different utilities for doing that. If you are on Windows (and can't get off) you might try `b = []; with open(filename, 'rb') as r: for ch in r.read(15): b.append("%02x" % (ch)); print(b)` in Python.

Comment: I got this: ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' ``` @tripleee

Comment: Looks like maybe you were quick enough to use a version of the comment which had a typo; please try again with the corrected code.